# Quick way to detect contact between two nodes that does not transparent space?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I want to see if a circle is touching the non-transparent part of the following image, not just the bounding box (which is a rectangle):

[image]

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: distance from point to rectangle: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44483/how-do-i-calculate-distance-from-a-point-to-a-rectangle

Comment: No, I'm trying to figure out a way to see whether something is touching the green grass or the transparent background.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking one step ahead. ;) You have an L-shape here, which you can deconstruct into two rectangles, from then on the problem becomes "distance of point from rectangle".

Comment: Ah. I was looking for a more convenient method. Something that knows where the picture is transparent.

Answer (score 1):

You could draw a [UIBezierPath](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/index.html) on your view and fill it with a pattern image, ie your grass.

Once you have the bezier path, use the `- (BOOL)containsPoint:(CGPoint)point` method to determine whether your point is in or out.

In a project I needed to draw multiple shapes, some were basic, other were complex. To help me I made a mac program displaying an image in which I could befine any complex shape by clicking on some points. 
Once the shape is closed, the program translate the absolute coordinates into your view size based coordinates, and exporting them as a Plist file containing an array of CGPoint.

In the iOS app, I just have to import the array and use the points array to create my UIBezierPath.
If you need more than just lines then you may want to add other things than just CGPoint in the plist, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: I will have some more complicated shapes. Is there a more convenient way of doing this?

Comment: I Edited my answer to give you an idea of how to draw complex paths easaly.